# Attempting to use org-babel to write “literate” Rust

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, rust

I'm playing around with writing Rust snippets in my editor. I can get org mode to format my things nicely and play nicely with `rust-mode`. But I can't evaluate my code snippets. I think that may be because Rust isn't strictly a scripting language, as the suggestive error, 
"error: no such subcommand: `script`"
provides, when I try to expand my rust source blocks. I could be just misunderstanding though.

Edit: I figured out how to solve my problem but minutes later, see answer below. I've moved onto a new question though: how I might run a linter or flycheck in org-mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hot diggity darn, but minutes later I discovered a crate for that. For future people landing on this question, all I had to do was run

`cargo install cargo-script`

and bam you'll be off and org-babel-ing. If you've got Cargo.el installed in your profile, you can evaluate pretty quick using Cargo-run. This may become how I write Rust going forward, if I can get flycheck to work too.

Comment: TELL ME YOUR SECRETS WISE ONE

Comment: So rust works in babel out of the box for me (doom emacs), but I want what you have - cargo script to run the rust in the code blocks!